# Error java executing: Couldn't find or load the main class

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to execute a simple java code (I have already compiled it with no problems) but it gives me the next error:

> c:\Users\alejandro\Desktop> java HelloWorld.java
>   Error: Couldn't find or load the main class.

The code is the next:

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Hello world!");

     }
}
```

- I have set the PATH variable correctly.
- I have deleted CLASSPATH variable.
- I have both files (.java and .class) in my Desktop.

Comment: have you checked typing `java` in your command prompt ?

Comment: @SanKrish yes it does work.

Comment: Compilation like `javac HelloWorld.java` and should execute like this `java HelloWorld`

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying the name of the *source file*. That's not what you provide to the `java` command - you specify the *class name*.

```
java HelloWorld
```

This assumes that `HelloWorld.class` is somewhere on the classpath, which would default to "the current directory".

If you had a package, e.g.

```
package foo;

public class HelloWorld {
    ...
}
```

Then you would want to put `HelloWorld.java` in a directory called `foo`, and compile and run from the root directory:

```
> javac foo\HelloWorld.java
> java foo.HelloWorld
```

Note how now the fully-qualified class name is `foo.HelloWorld`, not `foo\HelloWorld`.

Comment: that would mean that HelloWorld has a package declaration, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AmanuelNega: What would mean that? The code in the question doesn't have a package declaration, but I've shown an example which *does* have a package declaration to avoid problems down the line.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice the package declaration! My Bad!

Answer (score 0):

when you run the compiled file, you should use only the class name. The compiled file will have an extension of .class but you should not add any extension. Just use the class name.

change

```
c:\Users\alejandro\Desktop> java HelloWorld.java
```

to

```
c:\Users\alejandro\Desktop> java HelloWorld
```